# I am stuck on making this portion of my code, what do I do from here?

Tags: java, eclipse

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polygons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double side = 0; 
        double perimeter = 0;
        boolean valid = true; 
        var counter = 0;
        for (int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side of the irregular polygon");
            side = input.nextInt();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I need to add this following to my code now, but I don't know what to add from here, can someone please help me out?

If the value of side is greater than 0
Add that value to perimeter (Hint: perimeter=perimeter+side;) and
Set the value of valid equal to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is asking the user to enter an `int`, so the type of variable `side` should be `int` and not `double`. Alternatively, call method [nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) rather than `nextInt`.

Since you are summing `int` values, the type for variable `perimeter` should also be `int`.

There is no need for variable `counter` since you are you using a `for` loop and variable `x` is essentially your *counter*.

Also no need for variable `valid` since a simple `if` statement will suffice for determining whether the entered number is greater than zero or not.

After each number is entered, you need to add that number to the current value of variable `perimeter` – but only if the entered number is greater than zero. So before adding the number, you need to test whether the entered number is greater than zero. If it is not, you need to decrement the value of `x`, because it is automatically incremented before every loop iteration, and ask the user to re-enter the value.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polygons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int side = 0;
        int perimeter = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side of the irregular polygon");
            side = input.nextInt(); // store the user-entered number in variable 'side'
            if (side > 0) { // test whether the user-entered number is greater than zero
                perimeter += side; // add the user-entered number to current value of variable 'perimeter'
            }
            else { // user-entered number is not greater than zero
                System.out.println("Must be greater than zero. Please re-enter.");
                x--; // decrement the loop counter
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Perimeter = " + perimeter);
    }
}
```

### Edit

Due to OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70720157/i-am-stuck-on-making-this-portion-of-my-code-what-do-i-do-from-here/70720227#comment125021692_70720227).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polygons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double side = 0; 
        double perimeter = 0;
        boolean valid = true; 
        var counter = 0;
        while (counter < 5) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side of the irregular polygon");
            side = input.nextDouble();
            if (valid) {
                perimeter += side;
                valid = side > 0;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        if (valid) {
            System.out.println("Perimeter = " + perimeter);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please try again and make sure that all sides have a value greater than 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code so I could understand but how would I add the number to the current value of variable perimeter?  and check if the entered number is greater than zero? i'm new to java and still learning so I'm trying to understand, sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: This line of the code in my answer checks whether the entered number (i.e. `side`) is greater than zero: `if (side > 0)`

Comment: This line of code in my answer adds the entered value (i.e. `side`) to the current value of `perimeter`: `perimeter += side;`

Comment: Set the value of valid equal to false
Add one to the counter variable 
Outside of the loop print the value of the variable perimeter only if valid is equal to true
If valid is not equal to true, then print “Please try again and make sure that all sides have a value greater than 0” to the screen. How would I put these in the code, the terminal is only giving Please enter the length of one side of the irregular polygon
5
Please enter the length of one side of the irregular polygon
0
Must be greater than zero. Please re-enter.
Please enter the length of one side of the irregular polygon

Comment: @TheCodingJayy your last [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70720157/i-am-stuck-on-making-this-portion-of-my-code-what-do-i-do-from-here/70720227#comment125021692_70720227) does not describe the code in your question. The code in your question uses `for` loop but your comment indicates a `while` loop.

Comment: i could also use for loop and while loop for this polygon assessment. but I am testing the code here and it seems that the terminal isn't working properly? am I missing something here, I am still confused on this and am learning for loops and while loops.